# NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo doesn't match Microsoft Docs

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Using C# in Visual Studio 2017 15.5.3...

We have some unit tests that are expecting values of "0.01" (for example). The formatting method returns `$"{value:F}%"`. These tests are failing on both of my dev VM's because `$"{value:F}%"` is returning "0.010". The tests pass for the other 4 developers working on the project.

Based on the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) for en-US, `$"{value:F}%"` *should* be returning two decimals.

Upon further inspection, the `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` on my development environments have `NumberDecimalDigits = 3`. Why would my VM's be different than the other 4 developers that have passing tests? I just completely reset the settings to General in Visual Studio 2017 and the `NumberFormatInfo` has the same (wrong) values.

Additional details: One of my VM's is VirtualBox with Windows 10 on a Windows 10 host. The other VM is Parallels with Windows 10 on a Mac High Sierra host. All OS versions are updated/patched to current.

Comment: It's not a visual studio setting. Check your OS regional settings.

Comment: You would look in Control Panel|Clock, Language, and Region|Region (and Language before Windows 8)|Additional settings...

Comment: Interesting. So I went into Control Panel > Region > Additional Settings (under the Format tab). On the Numbers tab, it was showing 3 decimal places. I hit the Reset button and it changed several of the settings. No idea why any of that would have been different than default.